# How to show that $[\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2,\sqrt[3]5,i\sqrt 3):\mathbb Q(i\sqrt 3)]=9$

Tags: field-theory

How can I show that $$[\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2,\sqrt[3]5,i\sqrt 3):\mathbb Q(i\sqrt 3)]=9?$$

My idea is: $\sqrt[3]2$ has for its minimal polynpmial $X^3-2$ over $\mathbb Q(i\sqrt 3)$, which I justify by: its roots are given by the elements of the set
$$\{\sqrt[3]2,\sqrt[3]2 e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}},\sqrt[3]2 e^{\frac{4i\pi}{3}}\}$$
and there are no such elements in $\mathbb Q(i\sqrt 3)$. But how can I show that $\sqrt[3]5\notin\mathbb Q(i\sqrt 3, \sqrt[3]2)$ ? Is it enough to show that  $\sqrt[3]5\notin\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$ ? If yes, why, and how would I do it? I thought about supposing that $\sqrt[3]5\in\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$, so 
$$5=(a+b\sqrt[3]2+c\sqrt[3]5)^3$$
for certain $a,b,c\in \mathbb Q$ (or $a,b,c\in \mathbb Q(i\sqrt 3)$) and arriving somehow at a contradiction, but the calculation is very long and doesn't give me the contradiction I wanted. Is there another way?

Comment: Do you realize that $i\sqrt{3} = \sqrt{-3}$ generates the same field as a nontrivial cube root of unity? That is, $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{-3}) = \mathbf Q(\omega)$, where $\omega  = (-1+\sqrt{-3})/2$ is a nontrivial cube root of $1$? Because the fields you look at do not contain either $i$ or $\sqrt{3}$ individually, I think it is bad technique to be dragging around these expressions instead of directly writing $\sqrt{-3}$, which does lie in your field. It is even better to work in terms of $\omega$ since your top field is a *Kummer* extension of $\mathbf Q(\omega)$. Do you know Kummer theory?

Comment: Well, Kummer theory is more machinery than you really need. Look, your field extension is $K(\sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{5})/K$, where $K = \mathbf Q(\omega)$ for a nontrivial cube root of unity $\omega$. If you know all cubic fields inside $K(\sqrt[3]{2}) = \mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]{2},\omega)$, you can use that to show $X^3 - 5$ is irreducible over $K(\sqrt[3]{2})$.

Comment: In your last display, idm, I think you meant for that $\root3\of5$ to be $\root3\of4$. If you have done Galois Theory, it should be easy to follow the idea of KCd to work out those intemediate fields, but if you haven't gotten to Galois Theory yet, it will be more difficult.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Actually I don't know Kummer theory. Happy new year ;-)